# root can't open file created by NamedTemporaryFile

Tags: python, c, permissions, temporary-files

I've got a Python script running on Linux that does something like

```py
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as output:
    permissions = stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IROTH | stat.S_IWOTH
    os.chmod(output.name, permissions)
    subprocess.run(f'sudo ./some_executable -f {output.name}', shell=True)
```

where `some_executable` is a C program that contains

```c
fd = open(output_file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
if ( fd < 0 ) {
    perror("open");
    // bail
}
```

`some_executable` prints

```
open: Permission denied
```

It works if I either don't run as `root` or don't add `O_CREAT` to `open`.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The C program is trying to `open()` a file that has already been opened by another process for writing.

Comment: @martineau, why would that matter?

Comment: Because only one process can have a file opened for writing at the same time.

Comment: Really?  Then how do multiple processes write to the same terminal?

Comment: Terminal ≠ file.

Comment: You mean a regular file?

Comment: Creating the file with `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('r')` doesn't change anything.

Comment: IDK — although creating a read-only temp file makes no sense.

Comment: I `chmod` it right afterward.

Comment: Apparently that doesn't work. Consider this the end of the conversation.

Comment: Given the content of the currently accepted answer, I don't think this is a trivial nor naive nor bad question at all. Quite the opposite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with "The C program is trying to open() a file that has already been opened by another process". The problem is caused entirely by the default use of `/tmp` for temporary files, the special semantics of that directory, and some protections built into Linux (which I'll explain at the end of this answer).

You can verify that by modifying your code to create a temporary file in  the local directory instead:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".") as output:
    permissions = stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IROTH | stat.S_IWOTH
    os.chmod(output.name, permissions)
    subprocess.run(f'sudo ./some_executable -f {output.name}', shell=True)
```

This code will run without errors.

---

The error you're seeing is caused by a combination of three things:

1. You're creating a file in `/tmp`, which is world writable and has the "sticky" bit set.
2. You're opening the file with `O_CREAT`
3. Since kernel 4.19, Linux has the [`protected_regular`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt) sysctl:

   > This protection is similar to protected_fifos, but it
   > avoids writes to an attacker-controlled regular file, where a program
   > expected to create one.
   >
   > When set to "0", writing to regular files is unrestricted.
   >
   > When set to "1" don't allow `O_CREAT` open on regular files that we
   > don't own in world writable sticky directories, unless they are
   > owned by the owner of the directory.
   >
   > When set to "2" it also applies to group writable sticky directories.

Reading the above documentation, you're hitting "don't allow O_CREAT open on regular files that we don't own in world writable sticky directories". I'm sure if you check the value of the `fs.protected_regular` sysctl, you'll find that it's either `1` or `2`.

The solution is either:

- Create temporary files somewhere other than `/tmp`.
- Set the `fs.protected_regular` sysctl to `0`

I'd go with the first solution as demonstrated above.

Comment: This was a fun question, because I hadn't previously known about the `fs.protected_regular` sysctl.

Comment: Is this protection per process or system-wide?

Comment: sysctl settings are kernel flags (so they impact everything). The effect has nothing do with processes: it's all based around the filesystem and the flags you're using with `open`.

Comment: Not sure where that came from, but it was pretty fun. I like learning new things!